# What is the .NET alternative to the Rails stack?

Tags: c#, .net, ruby-on-rails

I presume that it is something like MVC4 + LINQ (or maybe NHibernate?)

I'm taking a dive into the .NET world (again) and would like to go with the best. Any tips and opinions?

Comment: LINQ is just a way to query objects. ORMs you can use with MVC4 are Entity Framework, NHibernate, OpenAccess, and many others.

Comment: If you want something more like Sinatra you could look into MVC + Dapper.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an exact equivalent. You could use a combination of ASP.NET MVC + Entity Framework (NHibernate) if you want.